# Signed MOD in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, signed

I'm trying to write a VHDL code to do 32 bit division and Module (MOD)...
The unsigned part works, but when I choose Signed numbers, the division result is correct while the Remainder isn't right!
for ex; -10 mod 3 >>>> Result = -3 & Remainder = 2 !
So what's wrong?

```
library IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
entity DivEx is
port(
    X   : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
    DIV_SU : IN std_logic ;
    Y   : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
    R   : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
    q   : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0)
);
end DivEx;

architecture Behavioral of DivEx is
begin

R <= (std_logic_vector(to_signed(to_integer(signed(X) / signed(Y)),32))) WHEN  (DIV_SU = '1') else (std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(to_integer(unsigned(X) / unsigned(Y)),32)));
q <= std_logic_vector(to_signed(to_integer(signed(X) mod signed(Y)),32)) WHEN  (DIV_SU = '1') else std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(to_integer(unsigned(X) / unsigned(Y)),32));

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Maybe you meant to use `rem` instead of `mod` ?  Take a look at the answer in the link above.

Comment: "The result of the modulus operation is such that (A mod B) has the sign of B and an absolute value less than the absolute value of B; in addition, for some integer value N, this result shall satisfy the relation: A = B * N + (A mod B)", IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.2.7 Multiplying operators. `report "-10 mod (-3) = " & integer'IMAGE( (-10) mod (-3));` yields "(report note): -10 mod (-3) = -1"